# Word Press (Ultimate Member) How to rearrange the order of buttons in login and registration pages

Tags: wordpress

I’d want to ask how to rearrange the order of buttons on the login page??
I have attached the link for your better understanding

I want to make the register button (left) comes first and then login button (right) for better user experience in the login page, and vice versa in the registration page.

*I tried to change the setting under WP-administration page – settings – Appearance – Login form – Login Primary Button Text
However, nothing changed.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Why not use CSS... can't you just switch their float properties just for this page? are you techy enough for that?

Comment: I'm not techy enough, Would you be able to explain that CSS float property part more to me? @Sagive SEO

Answer (score 0):

I see its an Elementor page so you could just add this to that page

**see more here:**
https://docs.elementor.com/article/516-how-to-use-selector-in-the-custom-css-tab

**Just, instead of selector use this:**

```
.uimob500 .um-form .um-col-alt .um-left {float: right}
.uimob500 .um-form .um-col-alt .um-right {float: left}
```

Let me know how it goes and good luck.

Comment: Appreciate that! Solved!! I really want to learn more about front end! I really feel the limitation of building a site just using Elementor.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the correct answer so it would get closed. Best of luck to you.